# Toggle content on Webpage using value from Python script

Tags: python, html, ibm-cloud

I am extracting Open/Close values from a Python application on IBM Bluemix.
I need to update these values dynamically as it changes.

It's a door open/close state and I need to show it in real-time on a web page. The variable is myData.

What would be the simplest way to do it?

```
m = svm_load_model("./door_model")
j,i = svm_read_problem("test_door.data")
p_labels, p_acc, p_vals = svm_predict(j, i, m)

for i in p_labels:
    if i == 1:
        myData={'door_status' : 'open'}
        client.publishEvent("BluemixApp", "123456", "status", "json", myData)
    else:
        myData={'door_status' : 'close'}
        client.publishEvent("BluemixApp", "123456", "status", "json", myData)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Can you show the code you are using to extract the values? The more specifics you provide, the easier it is to answer the question.

Comment: Added a code snippet. I need to publish myData to a webpage(will be the app homepage). It just needs to show the text, "open/close" as the value changes. Able to publish the message for any subscriber. Shows up in real time without replacement as an ongoing list. As for web page, I have limited knowledge of web technologies.